# Document Set Move

Tags: document-library, powershell

So far I have managed to move Document Sets using PowerShell from Document Library A to Document Library B. I found this article: http://www.sharepoint2010blog.nl/2010/07/20/Moving+A+DocumentSet+Through+Code+Pt1.aspx

It works great but only copies the document set to "Document Library B" root.

```
$moveurl = $movetoList.RootFolder.ToString() + "/" + $docset.Name
```

So my question is how do I move it into a hierarchy?

With this I should be able to get the folder:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://url
$list = $web.Lists["name"]
$list.Folders[$afolder]
```

But I don't know how to edit the $movetoList.RootFolder to that i use $afolder insted of Rootfolder.

Would be awesome if someone could help me out! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I Solved the problem, just wanted to post the script. The Script now moves Document Sets from Location A to Location B. Can be moved into folders aswell.

```
$moveFromUrl = "Url"
$moveToUrl = "Url"
$moveItemName = "Document Set Name"
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint") 

function checkItemToMove ([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList]$movefromList, [string]$moveToUrl, [string]$moveItemName)
{
    $docsetID = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBuiltInContentTypeId]::DocumentSet
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFolder]$docsetToMove = $null 

    $movefromList.Items
    $docSetListItem = $movefromList.Items | where {$_['Title'] -eq $moveItemName}
    $docSetToMove = $docSetListItem.Folder
    $docsetContentTypeId = $docSetListItem.ContentType.Parent.Id

    if($docsetToMove -ne $null -and $docsetContentTypeId -ne $null -and $docsetContentTypeId.ToString().StartsWith($docsetID.ToString())) 
    {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Found a docset: " $docsetToMove.Name " Lets move it"
        moveDocSet $docsetToMove $moveToUrl $docsetContentTypeId
    }
    else 
    {  
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "no document set of desired name found:" $moveItemName 
    }
}

function moveDocSet ([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFolder]$docset, [string]$moveToUrl, [string]$docsetContentTypeId)
{
    $url = $moveToUrl + $docset.Name
    $docset.MoveTo($url)

    [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList]$moveToList = $site.OpenWeb().GetList($moveToUrl)
    $newDocSetItem = $moveToList.Items | where {$_['Name'] -eq $docset.Name}
    $newDocSet = $newDocSetItem.Folder
    if($newDocset.Exists)   
{

    $newDocset.Item["ContentTypeId"] = $docsetContentTypeId
    $newDocset.Item["HTML File Type"] = "SharePoint.DocumentSet" 
    $newDocset.Item.Update()

    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green " Document set moved succesfully "
    }
    else {Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red " Failed moving the docset or setting ... "}
}

if($moveFromUrl -eq $null -or $moveFromUrl -eq "") {Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "No folder to move from"; Exit}
if($moveToUrl -eq $null -or $moveToUrl -eq "") {Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "No folder to move to"; Exit}
if($moveItemName -eq $null -or $moveItem -eq "") {Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "No DocumentSet name set"; Exit}

$site=new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($moveFromUrl)

[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList]$movefromList=$site.OpenWeb().GetList($moveFromUrl)

checkItemToMove $movefromList $moveToUrl $moveItemName
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$moveurl = $list.Folders[$afolder].ToString() + "/" + $docset.Name
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Tried the same line before but it didn't work. ATM I am trying to do somthing like this: $b = $web.GetFolder($web.Url + "part of url"); $moveurl = $web.Url + "/" + $b.FolderName + "/" + $docset.Name